# What does it mean for a metric to be regular?

Tags: general-relativity, terminology, metric-tensor

A problem in Carroll (a general relativity textbook) asks if a certain metric is regular. What does it mean for a metric to be regular?

Comment: It means that the metric, its inverse are well-defined everywhere in the space-time.

Comment: @Prahar that should be an answer

Comment: I didn't check Carroll's terminology, but besides being invertible, one usually requires that the metric should be smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the metric and its inverse are well-defined everywhere in the space-time.